# JSF - Target Unreachable, identifier '' resolved to null - workaround

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, facelets, backing-beans

Every time I don't set value to binding attribute (which is located in facelet) I get the exception;

```
jsf Target Unreachable, identifier '' resolved to null
```

The facelet usage both ways :

```
<my:tag ... tagBingingBean="#{myBean}"/>
<my:tag ... /> causes NPE
```

So my question is...

is there a way to catch the NPE and ignore it in case binding has no value?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, one way I know of is to create your own EL resolver. But maybe in an additional bean you can check if it is null and return a boolean that you use in the rendered attribute of your tag. Much easier... prevents accidental hiding of real error to during development.

Comment: @Kukeltje I did not see the example of how to do so :S Is it a listener or... give more details please

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=custom+EL+resolver+java

Comment: @Kukeltje I am not sure concerning how-to-do-resolver-to-catch-binding-npe so I am a bit confused :S give more details please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess maybe I could figure out how to use EL JSF 2.0 to really work it around using `http://java.sun.com/jstl/core`...

```
<composition ...>
<c:if test="#{not empty tagBingingBean}">
  <h:panelGroup ... binding="#{tagBingingBean}">...</h:panelGroup>
</c:if>

<c:if test="#{empty tagBingingBean}">
  ...
</c:if>

</composition>
```

I am not sure it is a final solution but, yes, it helps to work around the NPE issue in case of **null** binding attribute value